# How to query for Image saved in records Annotation using Javascript in CRM Online 2013

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, odata, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have one image attached with each record in my entity. I want to show these images in the records in a web resource just like a record picture. I am using the following code:

```
function GetData(){
//  var base64image = document.getElementById('image').src.substr(document.getElementById('image').src.indexOf('base64')+7);

    var recordId = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();  
    var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl().toString();
    var ODATA_ENDPOINT = "XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
    var objAnnotation = new Object();
    var ODATA_EntityCollection = "/AnnotationSet";
    var temp= "/AnnotationSet?$select=DocumentBody,FileName,MimeType,ObjectId&$filter=ObjectId/Id eq guid'" + recordId + "'";
    var result =serverUrl + ODATA_ENDPOINT + ODATA_EntityCollection + temp; 


    // Parse the entity object into JSON 
    var jsonEntity = window.JSON.stringify(objAnnotation);

    // Asynchronous AJAX function to Create a CRM record using OData 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: result ,
        //data: jsonEntity,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function(status){
            alert("success paa jee!!");
        },
        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("Status: " + textStatus + "; ErrorThrown: " + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

But I get an error `$ is undefined` when I reach the Ajax part. Basically every record has one Image in its notes attached to the entity's record and I want to show this image in a web resource as a record picture.

I am open to suggestions if there is a better/another way.

**EDIT:** I have edited the code and have updated the ODATA url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CRM 2011, I have used `two` Custom `Aspx pages` to show, the attached image.

Page 1: AccountImage.aspx have the following Control:

```
<asp:Image ID="IMG_Logo" runat="server" Height="50px" ImageUrl="AccountImageForm.aspx" Visible="false"  />
```

`In AccountImage.aspx On PageLoad`

```
if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
{
   Id = new Guid(Request.QueryString["id"]);
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
      ResetCache();
   }
   ShowImages();
}
```

The `ShowImages()` functions has below code:

```
function ShowImages()
{
  IMG_Logo.Visible = false;
  QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("annotation");
  query.Criteria.AddCondition("objectid", ConditionOperator.Equal, Id);
  query.Criteria.AddCondition("mimetype", ConditionOperator.In, new string[] { "image/x-png", "image/pjpeg", "image/png", "image/jpeg" });
  query.Criteria.AddCondition("subject", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "membershipcardthumbnail");
  query.Criteria.AddCondition("subject", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "membershipcardimage");
  query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
  EntityCollection AllLogoImageNotes = Common.Common.RetrieveMultiple(query);
  if (AllLogoImageNotes.Entities.Count > 0)
        {
         foreach (Entity Note in AllLogoImageNotes.Entities)
            {
            if (Note.Attributes.Contains("subject") && Note.Attributes.Contains("documentbody"))
                {
                    if (Note["subject"].ToString().ToLower() == "accountlogoimage")
                    {
                        HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("AccountLogoImage");
                        HttpRuntime.Cache.Remove("AccountLogoImageType");
                        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("AccountLogoImage", Convert.FromBase64String(Note["documentbody"].ToString()), null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
                        HttpRuntime.Cache.Add("AccountLogoImageType", Note["mimetype"].ToString(), null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5), TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
                        IMG_Logo.ImageUrl = "AccountImageForm.aspx" + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();
                        IMG_Logo.Visible = true;
                       }
                }
            }
        }
  }
```

As you can see, the line below:

`IMG_Logo.ImageUrl = "AccountImageForm.aspx" + "?time=" + DateTime.Now.ToString();`

In `AccountImageForm.aspx` write below code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache["AccountLogoImage"] != null)
        {
            Response.ContentType = HttpRuntime.Cache["AccountLogoImageType"].ToString();
            byte[] data = (byte[])HttpRuntime.Cache["AccountLogoImage"];
            Response.BinaryWrite(data);

        }
    }
```

In ODATA you can do the following:

```
  retrieveImages("/AnnotationSet?$select=DocumentBody,MimeType&$filter=ObjectId/Id eq guid'" + Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId()+ "'", function (JsonObject) {
    if (JsonObject != null) {
        //  debugger;
            var ByteString= JsonObject[0].DocumentBody;
            var MimeType =  JsonObject[0].MimeType
    }


 function retrieveImages(query, SuccessFunc) {
var retrieveRecordsReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
var ODataPath = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc";
retrieveRecordsReq.open('GET', ODataPath + query, false);
retrieveRecordsReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
retrieveRecordsReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
retrieveRecordsReq.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 /* complete */) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            this.onreadystatechange = null; //avoids memory leaks
            var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText, SDK.REST._dateReviver);
            if (data && data.d && data.d.results)
                SuccessFunc(JSON.parse(this.responseText, SDK.REST._dateReviver).d.results);
        }
        else {
            alert(SDK.REST._errorHandler(this));
        }
    }
};
retrieveRecordsReq.send();
}
```

Comment: isn't there any way to do it through ODATA. I can't seem to come up with the required query

Comment: Plus how do you upload aspx pages in crm?

Comment: @hkhan you have to upload aspx page, to CRM Server either as a separate Website or to the ISV folder.
and then use IFrame to display page.

Comment: I don't think so you can do it in CRM Online. That is why I am going for javascript and OData.

Comment: I had to make some changes to the code as some parenthesis are missing but this did the trick...now the next step is to display the retrieved image. Thanks Dot_Net Junior.